# Un-nesting a nested SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to building sql queries and could use some help. I built a query that works fine as a standalone query. The problem is I need to use it in a report using ExecuteScalar function and nested queries are not allowed, I tried to rebuild using joins but I seem to be lost.

Can anyone help me "un-nest" this query?

```
SELECT
StockType2Job.Loaded
FROM
  StockType2Job
WHERE
  StockType2Job.IdStockType = 
  (SELECT StockType.IdStockType
  FROM StockType
  WHERE StockType.Number = '1001716.00')
AND
  StockType2Job.IdStockType2JobGroup =
  (SELECT StockType2JobGroup.IdStockType2JobGroup
  FROM StockType2JobGroup
  WHERE StockType2JobGroup.IdJob =
          (SELECT Job.IdJob
          FROM Job
          WHERE Job.Number = '18-0085.02'
          AND StockType2JobGroup.Caption = 'Breakout Room 1'))
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how standard join syntax works? You have four tables you're trying to join - join them on the relevant columns (e.g. `FROM StockType2Job JOIN StockType ON StockType.IdStockType = StockType2Job.IdStockType JOIN StockType2JobGroup ON ...`). Then add the relevant `WHERE x = y` clauses after the joins (e.g. `WHERE StockType.Number = '1001716.00' AND Job.Number = '18-0085.02'`).

Comment: Here's what I've tried but I get a correlation error

Comment: SELECT
  StockType2Job.Loaded
FROM
  StockType2Job,
  StockType,
  StockType2JobGroup
  INNER JOIN Job ON StockType2JobGroup.IdJob = Job.IdJob
  INNER JOIN StockType2JobGroup ON StockType2Job.IdStockType2JobGroup = StockType2JobGroup.IdStockType2JobGroup
  INNER JOIN StockType ON StockType2Job.IdStockType = StockType.IdStockType
WHERE
  StockType2JobGroup.Caption = 'Breakout Room 1' AND
  Job.Number = '18-0085.02' AND
  StockType.Number = '10001716.00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query should work(on Oracle DB):

```
SELECT
   StockType2Job.Loaded
FROM
   (((StockType2Job a JOIN StockType b ON a.IdStockType=b.IdStockType) 
      JOIN StockType2JobGroup c ON a.IdStockType2JobGroup=c.IdStockType2JobGroup)
        JOIN Job d ON c.IdJob=d.IdJob)
WHERE
   b.Number = '1001716.00' AND 
   d.Number = '18-0085.02' AND
   c.Caption = 'Breakout Room 1'
```

Comment: I get an error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "StockType2Job.Loaded" could not be bound.

Comment: I probably forgot to change StockType2Job.Loaded with a.Loaded.

Comment: Yep that fixed it! Thanks Luca!